# Is it possible to enable in-app purchases for Restricted Profiles?

Tags: google-play-store, in-app-purchase, restricted-profiles

I've set up a restricted profile on my Nexus to enable my children to have relatively controlled access to the device.

Now one of them is asking for me to unlock a couple of features within an app via an IAP (Angry Birds Star Wars: Boba Fett Missions).

I'm happy to do this, but can't find a way to do so.

Before I'd set up the account I'd already purchased the "No Adds" IAP, and this is also purchased on the restricted profile, but purchasing the unlock on my account doesn't seem to have any impact on the state of the unlock on the Restricted Profile.

Is there a reliable way to either:

1. Enable IAP's on a Restricted Profile?
2. Transfer/Share IAPs between a Main and it's Restricted Profiles?

Answer (score 1):

Each user profile is using their respective IAPs, and so far it is not currently possible to share those purchases accross multiple users on the same device.

I don't know enough about restricted profiles, so I can't answer that part, sorry.

Comment: restricted profiles are not a new google account, they allow access to some of the apps purchased by a real account. NOT the same as an additional user profile.