# In app purchases not reflected on restricted account

Tags: google-play-store, samsung, in-app-purchase

I have a restricted account setup on my A8 for my daughter, and wanted to unlock some features of her game for her. I switched over to my main account and made the purchase, and it shows up there. But even after pressing restore purchases, force stopping the app, clearing the cache, and restarting the tablet, the purchase is not reflected on the restricted account. How do I propagate the purchase?

Comment: May help https://vector-unit-faq.groovehq.com/help/the-game-progress-slash-purchases-are-not-updating-for-the-restricted-profile-that-my-child-uses-on-my-device

Comment: Unfortunately, Google Games doesn't show up as an option in the app permissions list.

Comment: Possibly related/dupe: [Is it possible to enable in-app purchases for Restricted Profiles?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/56488/44325). Not sure about the validity of the answer since they were quite old, and I don't have experience with restricted profiles.

Comment: Restricted profiles don't have their own google accounts, so I don't think that one applies here.

Comment: Yeah, I think the answer is misleading, but the old question remains the same if it's even possible to propagate it at all.